# UTF-8 não funciona ao inserir dados

Tags: php, mysql

Eu utilizo `utf-8` no momento da inserção do campo `nome` em **PHP**, assim:

```
$nome = utf8_encode(strtolower($nome));
```

Ao verificar como fica o `insert` antes de inserir, a palavra fica correta, mas quando acesso o banco após a inserção, a palavra fica desconfigurada. Eu gostaria de saber o que estou fazendo de errado, pois já tentei mudar no banco para `utf-8` e ainda assim insere errado.

Agradeço desde já!

Comment: Na conexão com o MySQL você definiu para utilizar UTF8?

Comment: No seu caso troque a constante `MB_CASE_UPPER` por `MB_CASE_LOWER`. `strtolower()` não funciona com caracteres com mais de um byte (geralmente os acentuados e outros). Se o encode estiver certo pode remover também o `utf8_encode()`

Comment: MB_CASE_LOWER retorna erro: Fatal error: Call to undefined function MB_CASE_LOWER(). E eu não te entendi, se o encode tiver certo, remover o encode?

Comment: `$nome = mb_convert_case($nome, MB_CASE_LOWER);` não funcionou? foi errado pro banco ainda assim?

Comment: O problema não pode ser na conexão? Eu utilizo nos meus projetos a utilização do utf8: `$con = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=test', 'root','123456',array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));`

Comment: Disponibiliza o código que usa para a conexão com o banco e verifica se seus arquivos estão em utf8

Comment: SET NAMES utf8 deveria funcionar

Comment: Vou testar tudo isso e retorno aqui com o resultado

Comment: Um dos primeiros problemas que eu noto no código é o utf8_encode. Esta é uma função de compatibilidade com sistemas externos, se o DB e a saída estão no mesmo padrão, não tem sentido encode e decode. Mais que isso: strtolower não é uma função multibyte. Deveria ser mb_.... (a não ser que REALMENTE você esteja convertendo padrões)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Através dos comentários pesquisei como fazer `set names` com `mysqli` e ficou assim:

```
mysqli_query($conexao, "set names 'utf8'");
```

Inseriu corretamente os acentos no banco.